# iCloud redirect user to login page

Tags: swift, swift5, icloud, cloudkit

I would like to be able to redirect users to the icloud login page in settings if they are not authenticated. With the method below, I can simply go to the settings menu.
Which **profileUrl** should I use?

```
func iCloudStatus(){
    CKContainer(identifier: "iCloud.container").accountStatus { (accountStatus, error) in
        if accountStatus == .available {
            print("iCloud is auth")
              } else {
                  guard let profileUrl = URL(string: "App-prefs:root=CASTLE") else { return }
                  if UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(profileUrl) {
                      DispatchQueue.main.async {
                      UIApplication.shared.open(profileUrl, completionHandler: { (success) in
                          
                          print("\(success)")
                          
                      })
                  }
                 }
              }
            }
}
```